# Google Sheets API and a C# Console App

Tags: c#, msbuild, google-sheets

I´m trying to use Google Sheet API + C# Console Application.

The idea is to build an app to update an spreadsheet, it will be called on msbuild.

The first problem that I´m facing is the authentication, the example inside API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) uses an authentication that the user needs to provide during the application usage.

I would like an way to authenticate without the user interaction.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to use the authorization token. At some point you need to ask your user for some kind of user authentication.

Comment: Ok, but in a console app that will run on msbuild, it is not possible to ask to user.

Answer (score 1):

You could either

1)  pass in both the AccessCode and the ClientSecret as command line parameters.   See [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for examples of handling command line arguments.

or

2)  Store those parameters in an app.config file.  See [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for examples of app settings in an app.config file.

With an app.config file, you could keep real credentials out of the code you check it to source control and only put the real credentials into the config file when you install it on your build agent(s).